# A convenient way to bind to a local Service in Android

Tags: android

In my Android app, I have a service using the [local binder pattern](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder) and a couple of activities using the service.

The activities call [bindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) in [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29), unbindService() in [onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)  and implement [ServiceConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) to receive [onServiceConnected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceConnected%28android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.IBinder%29) callback when the service connection is available.

If I implement other callbacks of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), such as [onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart%28%29) and [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29), is there a well defined order between theses and onServiceConnected(), or can onServiceConnected() be invoked at any time?

I find this pattern quite inconvenient since I won't have the service connection available when onCreate() finish, so I need to litter other methods of the activity with null checks. Is there a more convenient way to do this? I would like a synchronous way to bind to a local service, so that I directly get the connection to it.

Comment: "Is there a more convenient way to do this?" -- do the work in `onServiceConnected()`. If need be, delay the call to `bindService()` until `onResume()`. "I would like a synchronous way to bind to a local service, so that I directly get the connection to it" -- that is not supported, sorry. Perhaps service binding is not an appropriate solution for whatever you believe that your problem is.

Comment: I do some work in onServiceConnected(), but I cannot do all the work there, I need to save a refererence to the service (as an instance variable in the activity) to be able to access it on other callback methods in the activity.

Comment: I am doing a music player, and need a service to keep music playing from a play queue in the background even when my app's activities are not in focus.

Comment: "need a service to keep music playing" -- for that, you need `startService()`. `bindService()` may not help, as if the user BACK-buttons their way out of your UI, you drop your bindings, and the service shuts down.